# extract sub string from a string in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to extract sub string from a string where space is the delimiter( ).
For the same I have used:

```
select
REGEXP_SUBSTR('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','[^ ]+',1,1) A,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','[^ ]+',1,2) B,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','[^ ]+',1,3) C
from dual;
```

which is resulting with output as

```
A          B        C
mobile  Motorola    Nexus
```

But my required output is:

```
A          B        C
mobile  Motorola    Nexus 6
```

Comment: How can you tell whether a space has to be used as a delimiter or not? For example, what if you have 'mobile phone Motorola something Nexus 6'?

Comment: Do you mean, you must extract the first substring (up to the first space), then the second substring (up to the second space), and then *everything else* as a single string, even if it contains spaces? Also, are you guaranteed to have only **single** spaces between the substrings, or could there be two or more consecutive spaces?

Comment: @mathguy Yes, I need to extract the first substring (up to the first space), then the second substring (up to the second space), and then everything else as a single string, even if it contains space. And its fixed that only single spaces will be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming above is the only pattern for which output is required, one way is to modify regex with something like below:

```
select
REGEXP_SUBSTR('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','(\w){1,}( \d){0,}',1,1) A,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','(\w){1,}( \d){0,}',1,2) B,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','(\w){1,}( \d){0,}',1,3) C
from dual;
```

**output:**

```
A      B        C
------ -------- -------
mobile Motorola Nexus 6
```

Answer (score 1):

In Comments the OP clarified that the substrings needed are: the substring up to the first space, the substring between the first and the second space, and the substring from the second space to the end of the input string. And spaces are single spaces (two spaces in a row, then, would mark an empty substring as the corresponding value).

If so, and if it is known that each input string will contain at least two spaces, then the problem can be solved efficiently (faster than with regular expressions) by using **standard** string functions. In the demonstration below I create the input data in a `with` clause, but that is not part of the solution; the actual SQL query begins at `select .....`.

```
with
  inputs ( str ) as (
    select 'mobile Motorola Nexus 6' from dual
  )
select substr(str, 1, instr(str, ' ') - 1)                         as a,
       substr(str, instr(str, ' ') + 1,
                      instr(str, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(str, ' ') - 1) as b,
       substr(str, instr(str, ' ', 1, 2) + 1)                      as c
from   inputs
;

A      B        C     
------ -------- -------
mobile Motorola Nexus 6
```

Regular expressions are less efficient, but they allow the code to be more compact - and they allow more flexibility (if the requirements change in the future - for example by allowing one *or more* consecutive spaces to be a single delimiter).

```
select regexp_substr(str, '([^ ]*) '       , 1, 1, null, 1) as a,
       regexp_substr(str, '([^ ]*) '       , 1, 2, null, 1) as b,
       regexp_substr(str, '([^ ]* ){2}(.*)', 1, 1, null, 2) as c
from   inputs
;
```

Notice the calculation for `c`: we read **past** the first two occurrences of (zero or more non-spaces followed by a space), and we capture the **rest** of the string, up to the end. This is different from the first two tokens (`a` and `b`).

Also - as different from the OP's attempt, which looks for occurrences of **one** or more consecutive non-spaces - both solutions I offered here look for occurrences of **zero** or more consecutive non-spaces, allowing for two spaces in a row to signify an empty substring (same as `null` in Oracle).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming names never starts with a digit, you could remove spaces in front of digits with REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
select
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','(\d)','\1'),'[^ ]+',1,1) A,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','(\d)','\1'),'[^ ]+',1,2) B,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE('mobile Motorola Nexus 6','(\d)','\1'),'[^ ]+',1,3) C
from dual;

A      B        C
------ -------- ------
mobile Motorola Nexus6
```